# error boundary for an api path in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I am trying to learn error boundaries, so I changed the url path and included error boundary package and added that component outside but still I am not seeing the error message
Can you let me know how to fix it. Providing the code and fiddle below. I googled but still no luck.

index.js

```
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ErrorBoundary fallback={<div>Something went wrong</div>}>
      <App />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

useFetch

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));
  }, [url]);

  return [data];
};

export default useFetch;
```

App

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import useFetch from './useFetch';

export default function App() {
  const [data] = useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/ddd');

  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.map((item) => {
          return <p key={item.id}> {item.title}</p>;
        })}

      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6tdyn9?file=src%2Findex.js,src%2FuseFetch.js,src%2FApp.js

Comment: What is the rendering error that is being thrown that you are expecting the error boundary to catch?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your response. I am confused I thought this was the error it will display in the UI ---> something went wrong. Can you update in my stackblitz how to catch the error. I am trying to learn

Comment: I've never been very fond of stackblitz. I think also the way it's rendering is also making it difficult to see that your code is actually working. Here's your same code running in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-boundary-for-an-api-path-in-react-hooks-ldndnc). I can see the error trying to render `data` as  an array when it's really an object. "Something went wrong" is rendered to the DOM.

Comment: can you let me know what changes you made, since for me I am not seeing any output in codesandbox

Comment: I didn't make any changes, just copy/pasted the code into a codesandbox. What are you seeing in the sandbox I linked to you?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually nothing wrong or incorrect with the code, it is working exactly as intended.

However, it appears that stackblitz is handling rendering the React error boundary overlay oddly where it's not obvious at all what is actually happening.

[image]

Normally when the React error boundary is rendered React will render/display a full-page overly UI with the error, a code snippet around where the error occurred, a brief stacktrace, and a button in the upper-right corner to dismiss the overlay.

[image: Edit error-boundary-for-an-api-path-in-react-hooks]

[image]

Note that the overlay is semi-transparent and that you can actually read the "Something went wrong" text behind it. Dismissing this overlay yields the rendered fallback UI.

[image]

Note also that this overlay is only displayed in non-production builds, e.g. when you are developing the application.

> This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the
> app crashes in production.
> Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.

If an error is thrown when rendering the UI in a production build *and* caught by the error boundary, users will see directly the rendered fallback UI.